# Django filter foreign key model in views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models, one is called `Books` and `BookInstance`, one `Book` has many `BookInstance`s,

```
class Books(models.Model):

.........

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a detail record for this book.
        """
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return '{0}'.format(self.book_name)
```

---

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):

    books = models.ForeignKey('Books',verbose_name="Books", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    keyrequest = models.OneToOneField('BookRequest', verbose_name='Book requests', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS, help_text='Key availability', verbose_name="Key status", blank=True)

    date_out = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Date Issued")
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Date to be returned")

......   
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular book")
```

I have a class based view in views.py that uses the `Book` model to show the total number of `BookInstances` for that book, Here's my views.py:

```
class KeyListView(generic.ListView):
    model = RoomKey
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'catalog/roomkey_list.html'
```

And I have a template that shows the number of all `BookInstances` for a `Book`,as shown below:

`{{ books.bookinstance_set.all.count }}`

But I would like to filter it out and show the number of **available** `BookInstance` of that `Book`, I tried to use add a Query manager in the `BookInstance` class but that didn't work , django never threw any error it just didn't show anything. Can someone please tell me the correct way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override view's `get_queryset()` method, and annotate count:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, CharField

def get_queryset(self):
    return Books.objects.annotate(
    available_books_count=Count(Case(
    When(bookinstance__status='a', then=1),
    output_field=CharField(),
))
```

Now in template you can do

```
{{ books.available_books_count }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, I was wondering though, is this the optimal way to interact with foreign keys  like this or is there a more 'standard` approach, sorry I'm really new to django

Comment: @UWGOOSE This way is more preferable since it's not generate additional query unlike `books.bookinstance_set.all.count` which will hit DB for each book in list. You can find more detail about annotation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/